# Gitlab : Failed to connect to localhost port 3128: Connection refused

Tags: git, connection, gitlab

I have just created a Gitlab account. And I wrote down the following command from my machine:

```
cd /var/www/projet
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/Alain83/touslesport.git
git push -u origin master
```

Everything is doing fine, exept for the last one, for which I get:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://User:password@gitlab.com/Alain83/touslesport.git/': Failed to connect to localhost port 3128: Connection refused

Whereas if I write `https://User:password@gitlab.com/Alain83/touslesport.git` as url in my browser, I can connect to my projet in Gitlab.

Can anyone help me solving this problem?

Comment: Remove any proxy configuration or start the proxy.

Comment: `git config http.proxy`? `git config https.proxy`? `echo $http_proxy`? `echo $https_proxy`? `echo $all_proxy`?

Answer (score 0):

I am working with Windows and cmder in order to be able to launch git commands.
The first two command result:

```
λ git config http.proxy
http://localhost:3128
λ git config https.proxy
http://localhost:3128
λ echo %http_proxy%
http://localhost:3128
λ echo %https_proxy%
http://localhost:3128
```

I am not able to run the last three with my environment. I also think that I have a problem with my proxy. I am working with a computer from my company. To avoid some problem with the proxy, I use cntlm. How can I set cntlm so that I can transfer files from my computer to gitlab and vice versa?